# Binding model adding string replace with -?

Tags: c#, html

I would appreciate some help on this, I am currently working on a item, the SAP CL Invoice Number is coming from CRM for example CL00131713, on my HTML view it is getting correctly mapped, however the requirement states there should be a - in the SAP CL Invoice Number. This should show as CL-00131713 like the image below:

[image]

My code is in my model.cs

```
public string SAPCLInvoiceNumber { get; set; }
```

In my organisation.cs class

```
result.Add(new InvoiceModel
{
SAPCLInvoiceNumber = invoice.SAPCLInvoiceNumber,
});.
```

Finally in my HTML I do

```
<tr ng-repeat="invoice in vm.invoices">
<td>
<!-- {{invoice.Number}} -->
{{invoice.SAPCLInvoiceNumber}}
</td>
```

I believe I need to do something like

```
SAPCLInvoiceNumber =   string.replace("CL","CL - " + string.replace("CL", SAPCLInvoiceNumber ))
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick :

```
 string pattern = @"CL";
 string substitution = @"CL-";
 string input = @"CL00131713";

 Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
 string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
```

You can create an extension function to simplify the call

```
  public static string FormatClNumber(this string cl)
  {
       string pattern = @"CL";
       string substitution = @"CL-";
       string input = cl;
       Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
       return regex.Replace(input, substitution);
  }
```

Comment: For simplicity I want to do something like SAPCLInvoiceNumber =   string.replace("CL","CL - " + string.replace("CL", SAPCLInvoiceNumber ))

Comment: You can create a method extension on string to simplify the call I ll edit my answer

Comment: Apparently I need to do as a different variable SAPCLInvoiceNumberr = string.replace("CL", "CL - " + string.replace("CL", SAPCLInvoiceNumber))

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a "-" after second char if it is not there. Its a very simple and efficient code:

```
string s = "CL00131713"; //SAPCLInvoiceNumber 
if (s != null & s.Length > 2 && s[2] != '-') s = s.Insert(2, "-");
```

I think this is better and more complete solution (eg. check if the string does not already contain the dash char, otherwise if you call it twice o a given value you will damage it to something like "CL--00131713").